# What should I do about a bully at work?

Tags: resignation, human-resources, termination, bullying, self-confidence

In my work, there is a person that disturbs me really harshly: he always bumps into my shoulder on purpose, he always curses me when he sees me, he always does from distance moves like he is punching me, he gives punches to my direction from distance every time he sees me, he blocks my way whenever I go downstairs, he gossips about me.

I talked to him many times to know what I did to him and I apologized, he promised that he will stop but he continues every time with his bad actions, I talked with many people about this problem and sadly, nobody could help me with him, luckily, I was in karate for 2.5 years and MMA for 1 year, I am pretty fit and I work out everyday, I am 5'10 and he was in boxing but he is obese and not in shape, he is 5'8, should I beat him? this guy really gets under my skin. Even after I changed job, he picks on me whenever he has chance.

Comment: "Even after I changed job, he picks on me" how does he manage to do that?

Comment: He does this in events.

Comment: What country are you in?  Would it be feasible to go to HR to lodge a complaint?

Comment: Please edit the post to have a clear question besides, "should I beat him?" Why can no one help you with him? How long has this been going on? Also, please add your gender since that is relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bullying at workplace: I'm confused how to take action](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/143408/bullying-at-workplace-im-confused-how-to-take-action)

Comment: @Joe, "**Should I beat him?**" If you ask us whether you should physically beat him, the answer should be **NO**.  Try to resolve this in a non-physical way regardless of how annoying the bad guy is. If you physically beat him up, then both of you will get fired, and many other worse things may also happen.

Comment: @joe, One suggestion is that whenever he starts bullying you,  you should raise your voice **just loudly enough** for him to realize that you are serious and say "**Stop it right now. I don't like it. Enough is enough with your silly acts.**" You should look straight into his eyes the way you mean serious business. Stop socializing with him for awhile so that he realizes you don't like his bullying you.

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane Gender is not relevant. If your company policy regarding workplace harassment fluctuates based on identity. it is out of date.

Comment: @Joe If you no longer work at the same place as this person, then this is no longer a workplace issue, it is a civil issue. If it's a workplace issue, this is the role of HR, and you should report the matter to them immediately, and for myriad reasons. If civil, you can file a police report; most states have clearly defined statutes for threatening behavior; YMMV. Either way, it appears to have escalated beyond what you can solve on your own.

That said, workplace or not, beating him would be a criminal offense, full stop.

Comment: @kmunky Fair point.

Answer (score 3):

Blocking, bumping, shadow-punching and cursing you are violent actions and harassment, not mere bullying. I advise you to document everything as best as you can and take it up with your company's HR and/or security. Also, note the existence of any security cameras for future reference. You've tried to deescalate, but it did not work; you need not tolerate this any further.

Comment: This is the correct approach at this point.  HR is there to protect the company's interests and allowing what is clearly workplace harassment to continue after being properly notified of it opens them up to significant legal liabilities.  Document, document, document, keep copies of all emails, take notes of all phone calls, keep track of every incidence of harassment.  Then read your company's policies and do what it says.  If they fail to act, contact an attorney and follow their advice.  My guess is that the company will be all over this because it could cost them dearly.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe you've already left the particular job/organisation where you first encountered this guy but now encounter him at work events. That being the case there's nothing you can really do to be completely rid of him unless a) the conduct crosses into illegal territory (e.g. he actually punches you which would be assault etc) or b) you're willing to leave this particular work industry sector entirely.

The first depends on him escalating this to, which I doubt he would do, bullies are fundamentally cowards who are unlikely to want to take you on in a fight. This guy sounds like the classic bully who just enjoys making you uncomfortable. The second is a particularly unpalatable option - and not one I think you *need* to take.

You'll notice I don't mention your *"should I beat him?"* as an option, because it's not. This would likely see *you* in legal trouble, particularly given you're someone with training in physical combat. So it's not an option, no matter how enjoyable the daydreams might be - in the real world it would only make things a hundred times worse for you. So, **forget it**.

So what *should* you do? Since you aren't seeing him day to day - **ignore him**. You've already tried taking the reasonable, grown-up route and he's not proven amenable, not entirely unsurprisingly in my experience since reasonable, well-adjusted adults don't go around behaving like some bad caricature of a playground bully.

As you've already (essentially) realised in the highly unlikely event he decided to escalate into an actual physical confrontation he's no particular threat to you - so at this point the only power he has over you is that which you give him. People like this like the pleasure they get when they see their targets discomforted, by ignoring him you'll not only deprive him of that which he seeks but you'll experience less stress yourself. He may even give up in time when he sees that you aren't playing his game any more.

I'm fully aware that this is easier said than done (I've been-there-done-that *and* gotten the t-shirt!) but it really is the most effective solution. Rest assured that this guy's "delightful" personality is unlikely to be solely manifested with you - those people he gossips to about you? They probably think he's an idiot too.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The other party is already acting illegally to the best of my knowledge, and OP has tried ignoring him already, which failed.

Answer (score -1):

## He's challenging you to a fight? Take him to a boxing ring.

This guy seems to be going out of his way to be physically aggressive towards you. Throwing punches in the air towards you isn't just rude, it's a provocation to a fight.

You may want to talk to a lawyer about what your jurisdiction's stance of the "fighting words" doctrine of self-defence is, but I think that something that almost certainly would be legal would be arranging to meet up with him at a boxing gym or martial arts dojo for a "spar".

Hopefully, once you've actually fought him, he'll stop being so pointlessly aggressive towards you.

Comment: I challenged him many times, I told him: "if  you are a real man, come and fight me!"  but he tells that he doesn't hit sick people like me.